# Scala Filter ArrayBuffer based on a Queue

Tags: scala, filter, queue, arraybuffer

I have an Arraybuffer which contains Int's. Beside that, I have a Queue that contains Int's too. I would like to remove from my Arraybuffer all the Int's that are also present in my queue. What is an efficient way to do this. Can I use the Filter function with something like:

```
newArray = Arraybuffer.filter(_ not in Queue)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `Set[A]` for that, especially if your `ArrayBuffer[Int]` is large enough:

```
val queue = Queue[Int] = ???
val arrayBuffer: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ???

val set = queue.toSet

val filteredBuffer = arrayBuffer.filterNot(set.contains)
```

Comment: The apply method of Set calls contains for you, so you can just call `filterNot(set)`

Comment: @soote True, but I think `set.contains` conveys the intention of the OP better. Brevity isn't always a necessary feature.

Answer (score 2):

If your array buffer contains unique ints (we can enforce this by converting it to a set), then the `diff` function is what you want.

```
val queue: Queue[Int] = Queue(1,2,3)
val array: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1,2,3,4,5,6)

array.toSet.diff(queue)  // ArrayBuffer(4,5,6)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that if there are multiples of the same value, this method will only remove as many of that value as exist in the queue .  If you have `Queue(1,1,2,3)` and `ArrayBuffer(1,1,1,2,3,4)` The result will be `ArrayBuffer(1,4)`  Using `filter` and `contains` will remove all occurrences of the same value if it appears in the queue.  So it depends on the desired result

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can:

```
val q: Queue[Int] = ???
val a: ArrayBuffer[Int] = ???

a.filter(!q.contains(_))
```